# I can not access my variable in EasyTableView delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I use "[EasyTableView](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView)" which is an extend UITableView. I encounter a problem as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"14.jpg",nil];
        photos = array;
        [array release];
        [photos objectAtIndex:0];  //this "photos" can be access
    }
```

but when i try to access the "photos" in the delegate method:

```
- (void)easyTableView:(EasyTableView *)easyTableView setDataForView:(UIView *)view forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger r = [indexPath row]; // r = 0
    NSString *imagePath = [photos objectAtIndex:r];  //this line cause : reason: '-[CALayer objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 

    }
```

Why the result to access photos is different? How can i fix it?

Comment: Not enough info. Where is photos defined and how did you defined it?

Comment: How is `photos` defined?  Looks like you need to use `self.photos = array` in order to retain the object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use photos as property as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* photos;
```

and in implementation

```
@synthesize photos = photos;
```

it will be accessible in delegate now

Answer (score 0):

The `photos` variable isn't retaining the array you assign to it.  When it is deallocated, the memory is being re-used to point to a CALayer object.  If photos is a retained property, you should use `self.photos = array;` to make the assignment.  If it's just a simple variable, then allocate it directly instead of using `array`.